# Approximate the sum of exponential functions

Tags: exponentiation

I'm trying to approximate the sum of $N$ exponential functions as one function.

Is it possible to do so, i.e. find function $f$ and constants $a$, $b$, and $c$  such that $$\sum_{k=1}^N c_ke^{a_kx}\approx c f(ax+b)$$

Comment: This is too vague.  Approximate in what region?  $A,B,C$ really big positive numbers?  Really big negative numbers?  Near $0$?    And approximate how?  You want the difference to go to $0$ in some limit?  The ratio go to $1$?  Something else?

Comment: Note that if you take $B=-A$ and $C=0$ we have $A+B+C=0$ so your function would need to be near (in some sense)  $kf(0)$ for all such triples.  But that covers a huge range of values...

Comment: Notice when $(A,B,C) \mapsto (A+\lambda,B+\lambda,C+\lambda)$, LHS $\mapsto e^\lambda$ LHS. If you want to preserve this basic property of exponential function, you have not much choice but setting $f(t)$ to $e^{\frac{t}{3}}$.

Comment: @lulu , A,B,C are not very big, I don't care about the way for approximation, I want the difference between LHS and RHS be close to $0$.

Comment: @achillehui , $f$ can be another function, not just exponent.

Comment: @lulu , it is known that sometimes the sum of exponentials can be approximated by one exponential, but not always. I was thinking about some quadratic function of exponential...

Comment: So...is your function roughly constant over every relevant triple of the form $(A,-A,0)$?  or $(0,B,-B)$ or $(A,0,-A)$?  Of course there are other triples that sum to $0$, but those seem like a good place to start.

Comment: No. I want something more general, perhaps not so close to the original, but more general.

Comment: @lulu, I rewrote the description, because mixed up some things.

Comment: Let $g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^Nc_ke^{a_kx}$. Then $f(x)=.000000001+g(x)$ is a very close approximation to your sum of exponentials. (Also, note that you have written a sum on $k$ in which there isn't any $k$).

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that you will be able to approximate it if you look at it as a sum of the exponential function. Replace $x=\ln(y)$ and have an exponential polynomial instead.

$$\sum_{k=1}^N c_ky^{a_k}$$

Since you want an approximation, you can find the reasonable fractional approximation for all $c_k \approx \frac{r_q}{t_q}$ and $a_k \approx \frac{p_k}{q_k}$. Assume that the least common multiple of all $q_k$ is $s$, it would be then $a_k=\frac{m_k}{s}$. Do the same for $t_q$ and find that the common multiple is w making $c_k=\frac{u_k}{w}$

Now replace

$$z=y^{\frac1{s}}$$

$$\frac{1}{w}\sum_{k=1}^N u_kz^{m_k}$$

And $P(z)=\sum_{k=1}^N u_kz^{m_k}$ is a plain integer polynomial.

Other adopted values depend on the precision you want or need.